# Cleanest way to insert ".js" after the path part of a url?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a `url`  variable, in which i'd like to insert `".js"` after the path part, UNLESS there is a `".<something>"` part after the path already.

So, here's a "hard coded" array of the start values and expected end values for each, which will hopefully illustrate the problem nicely:

```
var url_pairs = [
 ["http://example.com/foo", "http://example.com/foo.js"],
 ["http://example.com/foo/bars", "http://example.com/foo/bars.js"],
 ["http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz",  "http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz"],
 ["http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax", "http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax"],
 ["/foo", "/foo.js"],
 ["/foo/bars", "/foo/bars.js"],
 ["/foo/bars?quz=baz", "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz"],
 ["/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax", "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax"],
 ["/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax", "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax"],
 ["/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax", "/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax"]    
]
```

I'm struggling to come up with a clean and quick way to do this, but i'm sure it's possible to do it cleanly and simply eg with a regex.  Can anyone set me straight?  thanks, Max

**EDIT**:  testing solutions - here's a snippet i wrote to test it.

```
function convertUrl(oldUrl){
  //insert code to convert oldUrl and return the result
}       

$.each(url_pairs, function(i,pair){
  var oldUrl = pair[0];
  var expected = pair[1];
  var newUrl = convertUrl(oldUrl);
  if(newUrl != expected){
    console.log("expected \""+expected+"\", but got \""+newUrl+"\""); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a straightforward regular expression that will do it:

```
(\/[a-z]+)(\?[a-z=&]+)?$
```

No need to do any checks; this captures URLs without existing file extensions. Use as such:

```js
var string = "http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax";
console.log(string.replace(/(\/[a-z]+)(\?[a-z=&]+)?$/, "$1.js$2"));
// http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax
```

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, the following updated regex accepts underscores and digits in the path:

```
(\/[a-z_]+)(\?[0-9a-z_=&]+)?$
```

Here it is running on all the URLs you provided:

```js
var urls = ["http://example.com/foo",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo",
  "foo/bars",
  "/foo/bars?quz=baz",
  "/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "http://example.com/my_music_world_classes/edit_pupil?id=10199&pupil_id=157721"];
console.log(urls.map(function (url) {
  return url.replace(/(\/[a-z_]+)(\?[0-9a-z_=&]+)?$/, "$1.js$2");
}));
```

Comment: This passes all my tests and it's a one-liner - awesome, thanks @Purag.

Comment: Nice, I haven't thought of that! Too long didn't touch regex :/

Comment: @Arch Thanks! Yeah, I've been writing lots of them recently. It's a real puzzle sometimes!

Comment: @Purag - after passing all my tests, i've tried it for real and it's not working!  Can you see why?  `string = "http://example.com/my_music_world_classes/edit_pupil?id=10199&pupil_id=157721"` then, i do this, and it doesn't change:  `string.replace(/(\/[a-z]+)(\?[a-z=&]+)?$/, "$1.js$2")`

Comment: Use this regex: `/(\/[a-z_]+)(\?[0-9a-z_=&]+)?$/`. The issue was that the one in the answer doesn't look for underscores and numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have `document.createElement('a')` available?

```
> var a = document.createElement('a');
undefined
> a.href = 'http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz'
"http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz"
> a.pathname += '.js'
"/foo/bars.js"
> a.href
"http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz"
```

That takes care of all but the last two examples which require inspecting `a.pathname` and checking if there is already an extension and then not adding `'.js'`.

Comment: For a discussion of this solution, you can read https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Answer (score 3):

Using [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) this is simply solved by this snippet:

```
var uri = URI(url);
if (uri.suffix() == "") uri.suffix("js");
url = uri.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a simple `map` over a `split` and `join`.

```js
var urls = [
 'http://example.com/foo',
 'http://example.com/foo/bars',
 'http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz',
 'http://example.com/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax',
 '/foo',
 '/foo/bars',
 '/foo/bars?quz=baz',
 '/foo/bars?quz=baz&qix=bax',
 '/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax',
 '/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax'
]

function addExtensionToUrl(ext) {
  return function (url) {
    var parts = url.split('?')

    if (!parts[0].match(/\.(\w+)$/)) {
      parts[0] += ext
    }

    return parts.join('?')
  }
}

var result = urls.map(addExtensionToUrl('.js'))
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Yields the following array.

```
[
  "http://example.com/foo.js",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars.js",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz",
  "http://example.com/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo.js",
  "/foo/bars.js",
  "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz",
  "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax",
  "/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var string = 'http://example.com/foo/bars',
    index = string.indexOf('?'),
    url = index !== -1 ? string.substr(0, index) + '.js' + string.substr(index) : string + '.js';
```

Comment: Using my little test script (see EDIT in my question) i get a few problems with this one: expected `http://example.com/foo.js`, but got `.jso`
VM741:7 expected `http://example.com/foo/bars.js`, but got `.jss`
VM741:7 expected `/foo.js`, but got `.jso`
VM741:7 expected `/foo/bars.js`, but got `.jss`
VM741:7 expected `/foo/bars.js?quz=baz&qix=bax`, but got `/foo/bars.js.js?quz=baz&qix=bax`
VM741:7 expected `/foo/bars.xml?quz=baz&qix=bax`, but got `/foo/bars.xml.js?quz=baz&qix=bax`